# Unable to load asset/images/main_top.png in my flutter project

Tags: flutter, dart

I am getting error **Unable to load asset/images/main_top.png** in my flutter project. I have also included the correct image path , still it is giving error.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class WelcomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const WelcomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size=MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        height: size.height,
        width: double.infinity,
      child: Stack(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        children:<Widget> [
          Positioned(
            child: Image.asset("assets/images/main_top.png"),)
        ],
      ),),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: pubspec.yaml]

Comment: by `I have also included the correct image path` do you mean you added the path in  the pubspec.yaml ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in [this documentation](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/assets-and-images) you need to add `assets` under the `flutter` keyword

such as:

```yaml
flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/images/
    - assets/icons/
```

note the tab before assets, yaml files are sensitive to tabs.

Answer (score 3):

Tab before assets like this :

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/images/
```

Save pubspec.yaml then `flutter clean` in your terminal.